# File-local variables in `org-mode`

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have the following variables set in my org-mode file:

```
* conf
# local variables:
# org-agenda-start-on-weekday: 1
# org-clock-report-include-clocking-task: t
# org-duration-format: (quote h:mm) #fails
# end:
```

They all work great, except for `org-duration-format`. What am I doing wrong?

(I say it doesn't work because I have to run `(setq org-duration-format 'h:mm)` to get my preferred format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file-local-variables section of the emacs manual (`C-h i g (emacs) specifying file variables RET`) says:

> the variables in a local variables list are used literally, and are not evaluated first.

So just use `h:mm` literally:

```el
...
# org-duration-format: h:mm
...
```

You can also do something like this:

```el
...
# eval: (setq-local org-duration-format 'h:mmm)
...
```

but there is really no need to do that.

This has nothing to do with Org mode BTW. Try

```el
# Local Variables:
# bar: 3
# foo: bar
# End:
```

The file-local value of `bar` is 3; the file local value of `foo` is `bar`: `bar` is *NOT* evaluated, so `foo` does *NOT* end up with the value 3.